# Wix Error -2147217900 while executing SQL query

Tags: sql-server, wix, database-project

I am building a setup project using WIX 3.10. I need to create a SQL Server database from the installer, for that I am using a script generated by Visual Studio Database Project.

My WIX code is:

```
<Binary Id="SQLCreateScript" SuppressModularization="no"  SourceFile="$(var.TestInstallDBProject.TargetDir)$(var.TestInstallDBProject.ProjectName)_Create.sql" />
```

AND

```
<Component Guid="3B413DBB-603B-42BA-80A6-BA8ED5216ACE" Id="FornetDB" Directory="DirIIS" KeyPath="yes">

  <sql:SqlScript BinaryKey="SQLCreateScript" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" SqlDb="MasterDB"  Id="CreateScript" />
</Component>
<sql:SqlDatabase Database="Master"
                       Server="TUSHAR"
                       Instance="SQLSERVER2008R2"
                       Id="MasterDB"
                       ></sql:SqlDatabase>
```

It throws this error:

[image: it throws following Error while installation]

I opened file generated in Notepad++ but can't see characters. Error message has

[image: File In Notepad++]

Comment: Visual Studio Database Project generated create script has encodding **UTF-8-BOM** that is causing issue scripts with **UTF-8** encodding are running with out any problem.

Comment: Can i change encodding for Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I use custom MSbuild Task, that remove BOM information from text (SQL) file. Here Is Code:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace CustomBuildTasks
{
    public class RemoveBOMInfo : Task
    {
        private  ITaskItem[] _FilesToRemoveBOMInfo;

        [Required]
        public  ITaskItem[] FilesToRemoveBOMInfo { get { return _FilesToRemoveBOMInfo; } set { _FilesToRemoveBOMInfo = value; } } 

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            if (FilesToRemoveBOMInfo == null || FilesToRemoveBOMInfo.Count() < 1)
            {
                Log.LogError("FilesToRemoveBOMInfo can't be null or Empty.");
                return false; 
            }
            //var Files = FilesToRemoveBOMInfo.Split(';');
            foreach (var File in FilesToRemoveBOMInfo) 
            {
                var str = File.GetMetadata("Identity");
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(str)) 
                {
                    Log.LogError("File {0} not found.", str);
                    continue;
                }
                using (var file = System.IO.File.Open(str, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    int fByte = file.ReadByte();
                    if (fByte != 239)
                        continue;
                    fByte = file.ReadByte();
                    if (fByte != 187)
                        continue;
                    fByte = file.ReadByte();
                    if (fByte != 191)
                        continue;
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i > -1; ) 
                        {
                            i = file.ReadByte();
                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                ms.WriteByte((byte)i);
                            }
                        }
                        file.Close();
                        System.IO.File.Delete(str);
                        using (var oFile = System.IO.File.Create(str))
                        {
                            ms.WriteTo(oFile);
                            oFile.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and used in MSBuild script as:

```
<Target Name="AfterResolveReferences" >
    <RemoveBOMInfo FilesToRemoveBOMInfo="%(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths.RelativeDir)%(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths.Name)_Create.sql" Condition="'%(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths.IsSQLProj)' == 'True'" ></RemoveBOMInfo>    
</Target>
```

Comment: however script is still not running as script needs SQLCMD. So have to write custom action.